# MS Excel: Return value "$" sign if there's any value between two dates, if not, a "@" sign

Tags: excel

I'm searching for the formula that would return a "$" sign as a result IF there's any values/datas  between January 1 to January 31 2020 in the tabs TEST 1 AND/OR in tab TEST 2? And if there's no values in any of those tabs, it would result as a "@" sign.

tab name "TEST 1"

```
      A               B              C               D  
  ## DATE ##    ## AMOUNT ##    ##CATEGORY ##     
1. Jan-1-2020        10$          Internet        FORMULA??
2. Jan-2-2020        50$          Phone bill
3. Jan-5-2020         0$          Grocery
4.                                               Jan-1-2020
5.                                               Jan-31-2020
```

tab name "TEST 2"

```
      A               B              C                
  ## DATE ##    ## AMOUNT ##    ##CATEGORY ##     
1. Jan-1-2020      40 $          Rent            
2. Jan-2-2020       75$          Entertainment
3. Jan-5-2020      100$          Car repairs
```

P.S. The formula would only be entered in cell D1 of tab "TEST 1"

Thanks in advance for your help/suggestions!

Comment: How have you been searching? I'd think a simple `COUNTIFS` formula would do what you require.  Give it a try, and then edit your question to show what you have tried and where you have run into problems.

Comment: Hi Ron! I've searched on Youtube, Engine search, Forums for a return value in between dates. Looked for IF,SUMIFS, VLOOKUP examples but I didn't find the one that could sumrange AND give multiple criteria (don't know and have much experience in the different functions and combinations of formulas). Thanks for the COUNTIF suggestion. I've never used it yet. I just tried to do it but it gives me the FALSE value (the "@" for this example) but the expected result should give me the TRUE value for January (the "$" sign). Any idea how I have to compose the formula? Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Ah I just found the reason why I had a FALSE value! My date referenced cells  (the one that I use to compose the formula for the date range which is cells D4 and D5 in this example) had both different date format so I presume Excel didn't recognize the date range ("inferior or equal to"&January 1 2020 to "superior or equal to"??? (that's what I think, maybe a wrong in my presumption but for now it seems to work :P).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you mean by "Tab" but you should be able to adapt the below.

For efficiency and readability, I turned your two tables in **Tables** and have used structured references. This provides dynamic range references, and also clarity in formulas, in my opinion.

However, you can change the structured references to regular addressing, and have the tables on two different worksheets, if that is what you mean by "Tab".

I also `Name`'d your starting and ending date entries

***So long as the dates are real dates, and not merely text strings, the format is irrelevant.***

- If they are not "real" dates, then you need to change them to real dates.

  - *A real date can be formatted using the `Format Cells` method. A text string will not change it's format.*

I named the two tables `Test1` and `Test2`.

You count the number of dates that are between your start and end dates. If the count is `>0` then there is a match in one or both tables.

```
=IF((COUNTIFS(Test1['#'# DATE '#'#],">=" &dtStart,Test1['#'# DATE '#'#],"<="&dtEnd)+COUNTIFS(Test2['#'# DATE '#'#],">=" &dtStart,Test2['#'# DATE '#'#],"<="&dtEnd))=0,"@","$")
```

[image]

***with `dtStart` changed so range does not include any dates***

[image]

Comment: Like you, I would've send an image to be more clean and clear with my example but I had a person telling me that images was not recommended. Well explained and done Ron, everything works now :). Thanks for taking the time to help me out.and Yes, "when I wrote "tab" I meant a "worksheet" ;). Some people were using the term "tab" and others "worksheet".

Comment: @Max Glad to help. And your **data** is much preferred as text as you did. It can be copied to a worksheet easily. I use screenshots for **results** since they don't need to be copied.

Comment: Ok I understand! But I was wondering why does stackoverflow don't accept small datasheets that people could view, rewrite with a solution and send it to the forum after that?